# Compactness of product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

Let $Q$ be a position operator and $P$ its conjugate momentum. We would like to show that $f(P)g(Q)$ is compact if $f$ and $g$ are sufficiently smooth operator-valued functions and have compact support.

1. Let $\hat{f}$ be the Fourier transform of $f(p)$. Use that $(f(P)\psi)(x)=\int dy\hat{f}(x-y)\psi(y)$ to get the kernel $K(x,y)$ in
   $$f(P)g(Q)\psi(x)=\int dy K(x,y)\psi(y).$$
2. Use smoothness to show that
   $tr(K^*K)=||K||_2^2<\infty$.

Conclude that $f(P)g(Q)$ is compact.

How can I prove that?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275279/11127

Answer (score 2):

The kernel is evidently $K(x,y) = \hat{f}(x-y)g(y)$ up to a multiplicative constant depending on the definition of Fourier transform. If $f$ is in the Schwartz space, then its Fourier transform belongs to the same space. If $g$ is continuous compactly supported, it is easy to see that $K(x,y)$ as above it is at least continuous and it rapidly vanishes in all directions so that $K(x,y)$ is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2, dxdy)$ (that is your condition in 2). As a consequence of a well known theorem, the operator whose kernel is $K$ is therefore Hilbert-Schmidt, which is a sub subspace of the ideal of compact operators.